# Stripe - Monthly notification for six month or annual subscriptions

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

According to the Stripe docs if I have a monthly subscription I'll get an `invoice.paid/payment_failed` webhook telling me if the payment or successful or not

Then my understanding is that if I were to create an annual subscription, I'd only get one webhook each year notifying me on whether the new payment or successful or not...

My app works in such a way that if you have any sort of active subscription it'll give you access to more data, regardless if your subscription is paid monthly or every six months and so on... so, is there a way for me to get notified monthly about any active subscription regardless if they are every-six-months/annually paid?

Comment: What are you looking to be notified about?  Since the semi-annual/annual subscriptions don't renew monthly the only change that may happen to them is them getting canceled.  

You can also always retrieve a list of your currently active subscriptions if that's what you're looking for:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/list

Comment: Because I'd like to take a reactive approach in which I'd listen to webhooks and if the subscription was "active", I'd call a lambda function to give users more data, instead of being "proactive" and calling the lambda by a cron job or something similar :)

So your suggestion is fair when comes to a more "proactive" solution based on what I mentioned above

Comment: Gotcha.  So for a reactive flow you'd grant your customer access when their subscription is first created and becomes active, then you don't need to react again until there is a change to the subscription.  If the subscription is on a yearly billing cycle, then you won't need to react until the next billing cycle begins a year later.